# Listview item does not render xamarin forms on android

Tags: android, listview, itemtemplate, xamarin.forms

Got this funky problem.

I got a listview. and on winphone and ios everything works nice.

But on android it does not render every itemtemplate.
and if you scroll away from the item and back, it sometimes appear, but then some other item is gone.

Sample image

[image: Sample image]

The only thing I have found similar to this is fixed with

> HasUnevenRows = true;

which i do. i have search high an low for something that look like this or even fix it, but so far, i'm afraid i'm without luck.

Answer (score 1):

Could you attach code of Your adapter?
I think You're incorrect reusing views in Your list.
In *ListAdatpter* you should *@Override* *getView* method and refresh data in reused *convertView* accortding to new *position*

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = newView(parent);
    }
    fillViewWithNewData(convertView, position);
}
```